# Servlet Globalization NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN) doen't work properly

Tags: java, servlets, currency, number-formatting, globalization

I came across the following issue when I have been practicing on Java Servlet globalization:

> NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK)

is working perfectly while

> NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN)

is **showing '?' instead of '‎¥'.**

Here is my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Detecting Locale </title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        long number = 5_000_000L;

        NumberFormat numForUK = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
        out.println("<p>Format currency with UK locale: " + numForUK.format(number) + "</p>");

        NumberFormat numForJAPAN = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
        out.println("<p>Currency Format using Japan Locale: " + numForJAPAN.format(number));

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
```

**Output on Google Chrome:**

> Format currency with UK locale: £5,000,000.00
>
> Currency Format using Japan Locale: ?5,000,000

Please help me out to solve the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Look at the page encoding. Is it UTF-8?

Comment: 'Locale.JAPANESE' gave me this output: Currency Format using Japan Locale: ¤ 5,000,000.00

Comment: I'm talking about html page encoding. Do you see the results in browser? Can you show your response headers?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> from my web.xml

Comment: try instead of response.setContentType("text/html"); response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Perfect bro) Output is now: Currency Format using Japan Locale: ￥5,000,000. Please move your comment to answer I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try instead of response.setContentType("text/html"); response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");